# How can I implement Java/Swing controls that are disabled until after the window is activated?

Tags: java, macos, swing, focus

I am implementing a Java/Swing application for macOS, where it is common for most mouse button related behavior to be disabled until the window is activated. In other words, when a mouse button is pressed over an inactive window, the window is activated but nothing else happens. (There are exceptions. Some buttons when clicked will activate the window and also run their normal action.) Is there a way to do this? The basic problem is that by the time the application gets a mouse pressed event, the window is already active. My only thought so far is to correlate the window activated event and the mouse pressed event by time, which might not be completely reliable.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on exactly what behavior you're trying to elicit, but perhaps you wish to give your JFrame a glass pane, make it opaque and visible, trapping all mouse actions. Give it a MouseListener where when pressed, the glass pane is no longer visible (`.setVisible(false)`) allowing mouse actions to now reach the JFrame GUI.

Comment: That is an interesting idea for how to suppress the behavior of a mouse event, but my problem is how to determine whether the mouse event was produced by the same gesture that activated the frame. Only in that case do I want to suppress the action.

Answer (score 1):

You can make button's contains() depends on frame's currently active or not:

```
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JButton button = new JButton() {
        @Override
        public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
            return super.contains(x, y) && frame.isActive();
        }
    };
```

When frame is deactive and the region of button get clicked, button won't accept the mouse event since contains() returns false, button's parent get tested contains() instead (and parent's parent until any returns true), it still makes frame finally active, just button will not be given a chance to response to the mouse click.

Comment: As I tried to say in my question, by the time a mouse event is generated and dispatched, the frame is already active.

Comment: Maybe Mac OSX has got different behavior on this, I've tested the code in Linux and it does work, but it is not uncommon for the event handling to be inconsistent across OS even for Java programs :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the first answer I posted didn't work in Mac OSX, let's try a solution using AWTListener (which I do not prefer since it can be devastating when not handled properly):

```
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        private final AWTEventListener awtEventListener = new AWTEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                if (event instanceof MouseEvent && event.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED
                        && event.getSource() == button) {
                    ((MouseEvent) event).consume();
                    frame.toFront();

                    System.out.println("Special handled");
                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent aE) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().removeAWTEventListener(awtEventListener);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent aE) {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(awtEventListener, MouseEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
        }
    });
```

The idea is when frame deactivate, we intercept all mouse events, and when a mouse press event target at the button is encountered, it is consumed and we artificially activate the frame using toFront() (I tried without toFront() the frame also activate naturally in Linux, but it does no harm to call again).

When the frame is activated, we delay the removal of AWTEventListener using invokeLater() so that the button will not get clicked immediately right after we removed the AWTEventListener.

Comment: I think the problem here is that there are other ways to reactivate the frame, and in those cases the mouse event should be processed normally.